# What is difference between coarse structure and fine structure?

Tags: terminology, spectroscopy

What's difference between coarse structure and fine structure of atomic/molecular Spectra? I m trying to finding in Google image but I m not satisfied with images. i  also read in wikipedia.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Read where?

Comment: "I" is always uppercase in English.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to this site, but I know that these simple references should be in the comments section, which I cannot utilise due to insufficient reputation points.

So I am left to "answer" your question here as briefly as I can.

From looking up the images referred to in your question, it would seem that the information you require is [Vibronic Spectrum: Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibronic_spectroscopy), that is a mixture of vibrational and rotational degrees of freedom.

I regret quoting this verbatim, but it is written concisely by [Fine Structure : Encyclopedia Brittanica](https://www.britannica.com/science/fine-structure), and I cannot improve on it.

> Fine structure is produced when an atom emits light in making the transition from one energy state to another. The split lines, which are called the fine structure of the main lines, arise from the interaction of the orbital motion of an electron with the quantum mechanical “spin” of that electron. An electron can be thought of as an electrically charged spinning top, and hence it behaves as a tiny bar magnet. The spinning electron interacts with the magnetic field produced by the electron’s rotation about the atomic nucleus to generate the fine structure.